# matching parentheses in python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have something like

> store(s)

ending line like *"1 store(s)"*.
I want to match it using Python regular expression.

I tried something like `re.match('store\(s\)$', text)`
but it's not working.

This is the code I tried:

```
import re

s = '1 store(s)'
if re.match('store\(s\)$', s):
    print('match')
```

Comment: In fact it does work. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: Was something wrong with the edit?

Comment: @Jakub Hampl: Changing the regexp and important parts of the question does not help.

Comment: @poke Wow totally missed that there. I guess I was too concentrated on making it baseline comprehensible.

Comment: @larsmans just try the piece of code , I pasted. It's not working for me .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In more or less direct reply to your comment

> Try this
>
> ```
> import re
> s = '1 stores(s)'
> if re.match('store\(s\)$',s):
>     print('match')
> ```

The solution is to use `re.search` instead of `re.match` as the latter tries to match the whole string with the regexp while the former just tries to find a substring inside of the string that does match the expression.

Comment: Also needed to add 'r' prefix to regex pattern string.

Comment: It's not a quote. The OP never said "Try this" and his code does not have `s = '1 stores(s)'`. I suggest you copy & paste for quotes...or be more careful typing it in, because otherwise your answer is very hard to understand.

Comment: @martineau: No, OP wrote that as a comment first, hence the “reply to your comment”. The actual message was then later put in the question and the comment was removed. That doesn’t change the fact that it is still a quote (and *not* my text)…

Answer (score 1):

> Python offers two different primitive
>   operations based on regular
>   expressions: **match** checks for a match
>   **only at the beginning** of the string,
>   while **search** checks for a match
>   **anywhere** in the string (this is what
>   Perl does by default)

Straight [from the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#matching-vs-searching), but it does come up alot.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered `re.match('(.*)store\(s\)$',text)` ?