# Change the values of string in parenthesis which starts with Varchar

Tags: python, regex

I have a python variable (type unicode), which holds a query statement:

```
CREATE TABLE afg_temp (tadm1_code INTEGER NOT NULL, tadm1_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, test VARCHAR(4));
```

I need to replace all the values in each VARCHAR occurence with 254.
Initially I thought it would be enough to use the replace() function but this won't work as the numbers in the parenthesis are random.

Is there a way to do this using regex?

Comment: So, have you tried anything yet? Looks like a straight-forward task. [Matching parentheses with a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302942/matching-parentheses-in-python-regular-expression) is a solved issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with regexp:

```
import re
query = 'CREATE TABLE afg_temp (tadm1_code INTEGER NOT NULL, tadm1_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, test VARCHAR(4));'
print re.sub(r'VARCHAR\([0-9]*\)','VARCHAR(254)',query)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

s='''CREATE TABLE afg_temp (tadm1_code INTEGER NOT NULL, tadm1_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, test VARCHAR(4));'''
re.sub('VARCHAR\([0-9]{1,3}\)','VARCHAR(254)',s)
```

There are plenty of other solutions and you don't even need python for this. The easiest would be to use sed.

Comment: what if you have VARCHAR(8000)? ;)

Comment: good point I see that you got ahead of me by a few seconds with an answer that uses * . I will not edit my answer to avoid detracting the value of your answer. +1 from me